# how to enter user name , password , db name , in mysql connection by user input in batch file

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, batch-file

hi i am using a code to add a `sql` file to my `database` in a `batch` file . it works .

my code

```
C:
cd\xampp\mysql\bin
mysql -u root -e "source C:\xampp\htdocs\internet_wk_1.7\db\master_db.sql" kani
```

the case is i want to get user input values to `user name` , `password` and `database` name , instead of hard code those values .

currently my username hard coded as `root`

i want to do like this

user should get a message

```
please enter your user name :
```

when i did it

```
 please enter your password :
```

after that

```
 please enter your database name :
```

then the script shout proceed . how to do this , please help . thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set` with the `/P` option:

```
@echo off
set /p username=please enter your user name:
set /P pwd=please enter your password:
set /p dbname=please enter your database name:

cd /d c:\xampp\mysql\bin
mysql -u%username% -p%pwd% -e "source C:\xampp\htdocs\internet_wk_1.7\db\master_db.sql" %dbname%
```

You get more details if you enter `help set` in a commandline window.

Comment: perfect  it works , but only one problem , if i dont have a password, afer please enter your database name: , enter your password: again asking . why is that and how to solve it

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya: I don't understand your question. If you just hit enter at the prompt the variable will be empty.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name , yes but if i enter with out a value  ,it again asks for the password after database name

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya: not on my computer with Windows XP. I have no idea why it does that on your computer.

Comment: hmm , i am working on windows 7 . but it is ok , the code is working , thank you very much